# PHP Rounded Image

Tags: php

http://salman-w.blogspot.ca/2009/05/generate-images-with-round-corners-on.html

Here an example to make rounded images with PHP. It is working great. But it appears White color in corners. How to make it transparent?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766865/rounded-transparent-smooth-corners-using-imagecopyresampled-php-gd

Comment: In the above post which you said, It adding extra border like to image.. I would like to make original image to rounded corners

Answer (score 0):

All the images will be in rectangular shape and if you want to make a image with round or any other shape you have to any image format which has alpha data like png