# How would I convert 24/32-bit PNG images to paletted (8-bit) PNGs in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, png

I want to convert images to PNG format, resize them (width/height) and then convert them the same way http://tinypng.org does (to 8-bit paletted PNGs). How can I do this in PHP?

I know to convert to PNG, I use [`imagepng`](http://php.net/imagepng) (built in PHP function), and to resize them width/height I use a combination of `imagecopyresampled` and `imagecreatetruecolor` (correct?), but I'm not sure how to convert the PNGs to 8-bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert PNG to 8-bit PNG using PHP GD library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752514/how-to-convert-png-to-8-bit-png-using-php-gd-library)

Comment: @Herbert That function does seem to cover most of what I want. If I change `imagecopy` to `imagecopyresampled`, I can resize the image as well as convert to 8-bit. One question: the resizing is fairly poor quality, is there a way to make it better quality?

Comment: Maybe you could try using `imagecopyresampled` in two steps: 1. resize. 2. resample to 8-bit. Some people suggest using ImageMagick instead of GD; claiming the quality is better. I don't know as I have no experience with ImageMagick.